# Spring boot 2.1.0 Hikari CP bad password

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate, hikaricp

So I updated my Spring Boot to 2.1.0,  and now hikari is the default CP. According to some SO questions related to this I no longer needed to use the .hikari  in my application.properties file. My properties file now looks like this:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/deployHistory/deployHistory
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Now if I use the driver manager directly, like this:

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl);
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
stat.execute("create table ...)");
stat.close();
conn.close();
```

It all works fine,  However, when I use the Spring Boot JDBC template, and do a simple:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(...);
```

I get an error:

```
2018-11-26 14:27:54.772  INFO 7349 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-11-26 14:27:56.059 ERROR 7349 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-197]
```

What is the way to fix this?  All the pre-2.0.4 answers don't seem to work.

Comment: Show how `jdbcTemplate` defined/configured